# how to get information from an object inside json on spring

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

im developing a rest api for garanties, when I want to add a new product I send a JSON,this is the structure:

```json
{
  "Poliza": {
    "Cliente": "CLI-00012",
    "pago": "1",
    "fechaContratacion": "2021-04-26",
    "vigencia": "2022-04-26",
    "totalCubierto": "string",
    "numeroContrato": "string",
    "terminos": "string",
    "prepoliza": "string"
  },
  "empresa_id": "uno",
  "id_ticket": "string",
  "nombre": "string",
  "descripcion": "string",
  "ruta_codigo_qr": "string",
  "ruta_imagen": "string",
  "fecha_registro": "2021-04-26"
}
```

But when i want to get de Cliente field, appears an error "the value is null"

So this is my mapping Class:

```
@Autowired
ProductosController productosController;

@PostMapping(
        path = "/nuevo",
        consumes = "application/json",
        produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?>agregarProducto(@RequestBody ProductoInput producto )throws ProductoException{
    Producto prod = productosController.registraProducto(producto);
    ResponseEntity<Producto> response = new ResponseEntity<Producto>(prod, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
}
```

This is the Controller Class:

```
@Controller
@Transactional
public class ProductosController {

@Autowired
ProductoRepository productoRepository;

@Autowired
PolizaRepository polizaRepository;


public Producto registraProducto(ProductoInput producto) throws ProductoException{
    
    Poliza poliza = new Poliza();
    
    poliza.setCliente(producto.getPoliza().getCliente());//Here appears de error
    polizaRepository.save(poliza);
    
    poliza.setCliente(producto.getDescripcion());

    Producto prod = new Producto();
    
    //prod.setPoliza_id(producto.getPoliza().getId());
    prod.setCliente_id(producto.getPoliza().getCliente());
    prod.setEmpresa_id(producto.getEmpresa_id());
    prod.setId_ticket(producto.getId_ticket());
    prod.setNombre(producto.getNombre());
    prod.setDescripcion(producto.getDescripcion());
    prod.setRuta_codigo_qr(producto.getRuta_codigo_qr());
    prod.setRuta_imagen(producto.getRuta_imagen());
    prod.setFecha_registro(producto.getFecha_registro());
    
    Producto newProducto = productoRepository.save(prod);
    
    return newProducto;
}
```

This is the ProductoInputClass:

```
public class ProductoInput {

private PolizaInput poliza;

private String cliente_id;
private String poliza_id;
private String empresa_id;
private String id_ticket;
private String nombre;
private String descripcion;
private String ruta_codigo_qr;
private String ruta_imagen;
private Date fecha_registro;

//getters and setters
}
```

This is the PolizaIput Class

```
public class PolizaInput {

private String id;
private String cliente;
private String pago;
private Date fechaContratacion;
private Date vigencia;
private String estatusPago;
private float totalCubierto;
private String numeroContrato;
private String terminos;
private String prepoliza;
//Getters and setters

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Poliza [id =");
    builder.append("id, Cliente =");
    builder.append("cliente, pago =");
    builder.append("pago, fechaContratacion =");
    builder.append("fechaContratacion, vigencia =");
    builder.append("vigencia, totalCubierto =");
    builder.append("totalCubierto, numeroContrato =");
    builder.append("numeroContrato, terminos =");
    builder.append("terminos, prepoliza =");
    builder.append("prepoliza");
    builder.append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

}

So, how can I access to a Poliza fields from the JSON sent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Gson library from Google it provides two methods **toJson()** and **fromJson()** to convert Java objects to JSON and vice-versa.
https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: It didn´t work :( I printed the json converted object and this is the result
{"empresa_id":"uno","id_ticket":"string","nombre":"string","descripcion":"string","ruta_codigo_qr":"string","ruta_imagen":"string","fecha_registro":"abr. 25, 2021"}

It didn´t recognize the object Poliza :c

Answer (score 0):

You should use lower case for cliente instead Cliente fieldname
you can use this post request body

```
        {
        "poliza": {
        "cliente": "CLI-00012",
        "pago": "1",
        "fechaContratacion": "2021-04-26",
        "vigencia": "2022-04-26",
        "totalCubierto": "string",
        "numeroContrato": "string",
        "terminos": "string",
        "prepoliza": "string"
      },
      "empresa_id": "uno",
      "id_ticket": "string",
      "nombre": "string",
      "descripcion": "string",
      "ruta_codigo_qr": "string",
      "ruta_imagen": "string",
      "fecha_registro": "2021-04-26"
    }
```